# axes of matplotlib graph does not go in numerical order when plotting certain values

Tags: python, matplotlib

the axes of the graph plotted by `matplotlib` becomes not in numerical order after plotting certain points

just wanted to make a program to plot and connect points on a graph to get the hang of `matplotlib` and `tkinter`

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
root = Tk()
x_points = []
y_points = []
def plot():
    global x_points
    global y_points
    x = entry_x.get()
    y = entry_y.get()
    x_points.append(x)
    y_points.append(y)
    plt.plot(x_points,y_points)
    plt.show()



prompt_x = Label(root, text = 'enter the x coordinate')
prompt_y = Label(root, text = 'enter the y coordinate')
button = Button(text = 'click to plot point', command = plot)
entry_x = Entry()
entry_y = Entry()
prompt_x.grid(row = 0)
prompt_y.grid(row = 1)
entry_x.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
entry_y.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
button.grid(row=2)


plt.show()
root.mainloop()
```

by plotting the points in order:

```
(1,2)
(2,5)
(1.5,3)
```

I expect it to form a `triangle`, 
but results in the line just changing colour and screwing axes up

Comment: If you plot like this: `plt.plot([1, 2, 1.5], [2, 5, 3]);plt.show()`, you'll get the line on the graph. What does "screwing axes up" mean? Please include the graph you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your widget is returning a String, you need to convert it to a numeric type if you want to plot it correctly.

```
x = float(entry_x.get())
y = float(entry_y.get())
```